# Use socket.io to push a message to a node script

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to develop a push server for a desktop client of mine. I am using node.js to develop this server. So the socket.io lib allows us to push notifications to html but is it possible to send push notifications to another node.js script.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just use get in the other node.js

```
//On the pinging script
  var socket = io.connect(YOUR_NODEJS_SERVER_LOCATION);
  .....
  });
```

Treat it like it's a browser the server will wait for this connection request.

Comment: var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8001');
                  ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'connect'
    at Object.<anonymous> (/User/Desktop/PushServer/SampleClient.js:3:19)

Comment: Thanks for replying but I had already tried that before, and got the above error. I got the above error as I have imported socket.io using the following line - var io = require('socket.io');